# Getting position for Cytoscape desktop for using in Cytoscape js

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape

So, my network is really large, 3000 nodes and 7000 edges. All advance layouting algorithm will make the browser frozen. My idea is to use precalculated position in the json that I will load in Cytoscape js. I think using precalculated position will make the rendering faster and lighter.

Now, how can I get this position from Cytoscape desktop app because I display it in the desktop app and I am quite satsify with the result from applying on of the algorithm in the desktop app?

If I can get the position from the desktop app, I can add it to the json data to load in the web using Cytoscape js.Thank you.

Comment: have you looked at [performance](http://js.cytoscape.org/#performance) ?

Comment: I think that optimizing performance is important but if I can just define the position, it would be better, right? That way, everytime the network load, the layout calculation is not needed. What I'm thinking now is to manually adjust some position in the web and then I create some js function to print the position because there is a function in cytoscape js to do that. Maybe I will try to read cytoscape CLI. I still search any other options though.

Answer (score 4):

You can run a layout in

- the browser and then save the layout result using [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) (or `copy()` in the debug console),
- Node.js (using Cytoscape.js directly) and then save the layout result using `fs.writeFile()`,
- Node.js using [Cytosnap](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytosnap) (which uses Phantom) and then save the layout result using using `fs.writeFile()`, or
- Cytoscape desktop software by importing JSON, running a layout, and then exporting JSON (only reasonable for non-server, non-automated usecases, i.e. just a handful of graphs).